# How to make address returned by JNI FindClass return always the same address

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface

In my C program, I have the following code:

```
jclass class;
jmethodID method;


class = (*env)->FindClass(env, "java/lang/Short");
method = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, class, "<init>", "(S)V");
printf("First: class=%p * method=%p\n", class, method);


class = (*env)->FindClass(env, "java/lang/Short");
method = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, class, "<init>", "(S)V");
printf("Second: class=%p * method=%p\n", class, method);
```

When I compile the program (in GCC) and run it, it gives the following output:

```
First: class=0x7f55ac089450 * method=0x7f55ac0d99b8

Second: class=0x7f55ac089458 * method=0x7f55ac0d99b8
```

As you can see, the address of the class is different each time `FindClass` is called. I thought the address of the class was static and it wouldn't change during the lifetime of our program. In fact, when one reads this well known article from IBM on how to optimize C code using JNI (https://developer.ibm.com/languages/java/articles/j-jni/#notc) they say to cache the value returned by `FindClass` (so one would expect that it doesn't change). But, if you later on use this cached value in a JNI function call, it will make your C program crash (as it is using a wrong address of the Java class).

Another strange thing is that when caching the value returned by `FindClass` for the class `java/lang/Integer` (instead of `java/lang/Short` as posted above), and then use this cached value later on everything works correctly and as expected (i.e. no crash).

Comment: What guarantees that the address will be the same when you call `FindClass`?  I wouldn't expect that in the slightest unless the direct value of the short- I mean int - were the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What `FindClass` returns is [a local reference](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni#local-and-global-references) a Java `Class` object.

In your example, you get two separate references - but both of them may be referencing the same object.

Consider what would happen if the behavior had been what you expected and you got the same reference for both `FindClass` calls:

```
first = (*env)->FindClass(env, "java/lang/Short");
second = (*env)->FindClass(env, "java/lang/Short");
(*env)->DeleteLocalRef(env, first);
method = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, second, "<init>", "(S)V");  // OOPS! this reference may no longer be valid
```

In actuality the above will work fine, because `first` and `second` will be separate references to `Class<Short>`.

Comment: Perfect! By reading your solution and the page that you have sent the link I managed to solve the issue!