# JNI: is the return value of GetObjectClass supposed to vary for the same object?

Tags: java, c++, java-8, java-native-interface

Here's some JNI behavior that's baffling me on OpenJDK 8.272 (code is in C++):

```
JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL Java_/*name omitted*/(JNIEnv *env, jclass, jobject obj) {
  assert(env->GetObjectClass(obj) == env->GetObjectClass(obj));
  return 0;
}
```

This assert fails. Is this expected behavior? If so, for how long is it safe to use a jclass returned by `GetObjectClass`? Should I Just be calling `GetObjectClass` again every time I need access to the `jclass`?

Comment: `jclass` is basically a handle to back into the JVM to the class object.  You have 2 open local references to the class object (`GetObjectClass` called 2 times) and therefore 2 handles.  There is no reason why the 2 local references (handles) should have the same value.

Comment: `jobject` and `jclass` lifetimes are discussed in the JNI Spoecification, but within a single JNI method why would you call it again when you already have the result?

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66281871/how-to-make-address-returned-by-jni-findclass-return-always-the-same-address/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To cite [the specification](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/specs/jni/functions.html#local-references):

> #### Local References
>
> Local references are valid for the duration of a native method call. They are freed automatically after the native method returns. Each local reference costs some amount of Java Virtual Machine resource. Programmers need to make sure that native methods do not excessively allocate local references. Although local references are automatically freed after the native method returns to Java, excessive allocation of local references may cause the VM to run out of memory during the execution of a native method.

So no, within a single execution of your native method you should not call `GetObjectClass` again every time you need access to the `jclass`. Keep the reference and re-use it, for the duration of the current invocation.

You can test whether two references point to the same object with the function [`IsSameObject`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/specs/jni/functions.html#issameobject). However, as said above, when a function is supposed to evaluate to the same object you are already referencing, you should avoid creating a new reference.

Comment: this makes sense! Where in the specification is it marked which references are local references? I think I might be storing quite a few of them for far too long...

Comment: @MatthewMilano All references you obtain from the JNI API except those about weak and global references are local references.